# Why do-while dosen't respond to .equals

Tags: java

I'm setting up this do- while loop . Where do i need to correct this code
so when 000000 is given , the loop ends.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String am ;
   {
   do
   {  System.out.println("give am number");
        am = kb.next();   
       if (am.matches("[0-9]+") && am.length() <= 6)
        {System.out.println("am = "+am);
        {break;}}
        else 
       {System.out.println("wrong try again");  
            am = kb.next();
       }   
   } while(!"000000".equals(am));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help the readability of your question if you would format your code in a more conventional way, with consistent indentation as well. (Aside from anything else, the way you've formatted it at the moment makes it look like you expect the second call to `kb.next()` to be within the `else` fork, and it's not.)

Comment: Yikes so many braces

Comment: if you want to check if it is or not `"000000"` why compare with `"[000000]"`? (regular expression uses `[]` to match any of its elements, but `equals` is not using regular expression)

Comment: This won't even compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you are checking for *equality,* not *matching.*  `"000000"` is not equal to `"[000000]"`, so the loop keeps going.

It's not completely clear what you want, but I think just ditching the square braces is probably the answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying..Well what i want to achieve is that when the number that is given from the user is 000000 the loop has to end

Comment: Then you should just delete the square braces.

Comment: sadly it didn't work

Comment: @ted Please explain how it didn't work, as well as formatting your code better, because it definitely looks like your formatting is misleading you as to what your code is actually doing.

Comment: when the input by the user is 000000 it should be stopped by the while statement but it dosen't

Comment: It does stop when I run the code you have in your question.  (It also stops when you input any other 6-digit number, but that's another bug.)